# Extracting peaks from CSV file

Tags: python, csv, import-from-csv

I was wondering if there is a simple way to automatically cut up a dataset to have little blocks of data containing a peak. 
[image]

This is my data, and I want to eventually overlay the peaks by cross correlation, but I need them with separate data blocks first.

I tried finding them by numerical differentiation:

```
diff_voltage = zeros(len(voltage))
for i in range(len(voltage)-1):
    if (voltage[i] > 0.32):
        diff_voltage[i] = (voltage[i+1]-voltage[i])/(29.31/len(voltage))
    else:
        diff_voltage[i] = 0
```

But that only picks up 4/7 peaks and gives some noise terms.

So is there any way to find the top value/index of every peak and then cut out the data thats +/- 50 datapoints around that?

This is the first peak zoomed in
[image]

It's a big dataset so couldn't do a pastebin: http://pietrow.net/data/results.csv

Comment: While your effort and question is certainly valid, it's lacking data: i.e. post a sample line or two of your csv file. Because, it stands, there's no way to tell you what to do other than glossing statements.

Comment: It's a big dataset so couldn't do a pastebin: http://pietrow.net/data/results.csv